# emptying buffer with getchar() is erasing return value

Tags: c

i'm having trouble with getchar()!

```
if (i < 3) {
    printf("zu kurz\n");
    stdin_leeren();
    return -4;

void stdin_leeren(void) {
    while (getchar() != '\n') {
    }
}
```

after using function stdin_leeren which is supposed to clean the buffer, i'm not able to send a return value to the main function. I have to press the enter button although i would expect the return value -4 to be sent automatically...

Comment: \n is line separator so it isnt strange if you need to press enter. If you want the string terminator char use '\0'

Comment: `stdin_leeren` is reading `stdin` until it gets a `\n`. You should not call `stdin_leeren` unless you know that there are characters in the input buffer.

Comment: i'm not using strings (not allowed to, in this task) just repeatedly taking chars from the buffer with getchar()...

Comment: yes when i know for sure there are chars left i need to press enter, however if the buffer is empty and i call stdin_leeren i don't need to press enter. confusing :(

Comment: You should also check for EOF in `stdin_leeren()`:  `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`.  Otherwise, your code goes into an infinite loop if it does encounter EOF.  Note that `getchar()` returns an `int` and not a `char`.

Comment: If the buffer is empty then `getchar()` will wait for keys to be pressed

Comment: OP, You have the logic backwards, You only need to call stdin_leeren() when there are characters in the input stream,  Otherwise, the call will hang (as you have seen)